# Cannot Update or Install Apps from PlayStore

Tags: google-play-store, htc, htc-flyer

Currently I'm using HTC Flyer. I cannot update or install apps from appstore
and tried resetting the tablet. Still no use.

> Device Info:
>
> HTC-Flyer P510e
>
> Android Version : 3.2.1

Any way to resolve this??

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Couldn't find any error. When I try to download an app from store progress bar keeps scrolling..

Comment: @Pankaj I also tried with different Account

Comment: Are you trying with Wifi/3G?

Comment: @Pankaj Yes. WIFI.

Comment: Can you add more info regarding the android version you have?

Comment: @Pankaj I have updated my question with device info

Comment: Can you download from the PlayStore through a browser?